# Convincing boss to allow team members to go on business travel

Tags: communication, travel

I work as an IT Auditor as the lead / most senior member of a team of 5, including myself. Currently we are looking to work with a new vendor to replace our current vendor for a specific business process.

Today my boss called me into a meeting and stated he would like me to go onsite at the vendor for a security risk assessment. This proposed vendor is fairly large, and will be handling sensitive company information (PII). The scope is fairly involved and includes many areas to review such as access, data protection, BCP/DRP...etc.

Given the size of the proposed vendor and the sensitivity of the service they provide to us, I would like at least 1 other member of the team to accompany me onsite for process walkthroughs, interviews...etc. to maximize coverage. However, when I raised my request to my boss, he seemed hesitant and stated we have other pressing work (ex: SOX preparation) to do. If 2 members go, 3 will remain, which I feel is adequate coverage.

I also think this is a good learning opportunity for younger team members. (I stated in some of my previous questions team members sometimes lack experience). Meeting and learning to evaluate a vendor can be quite educational.

**How can I persuade my manager allow additional team members to accompany me?**

Answer (score 4):

This is about money and progress from the manager perspective.  They likely pay for travel and pay you during the event while at the same time seek to make progress on the products that anyone going is not doing anything to progress while there.  In essence it's a big financial hit on the company.

Goal:
Demonstrate the ROI(Return on Investment) for having another person going.

- Personal experience will return x to the company which will profit in y
- A second person will provide x during the event which in turn will benefit the company in y
- Current project load is covered by 3 employees so there is bandwidth for 2 to go and not risk any project milestones

Be specific and thorough in your data and facts.  This shows that you have considered the company benefit thoroughly as well as the individual benefits.  If you numbers line up and are good the manager should agree, but if the numbers just don't line up in favor of the company you are really asking the company to fund personal development time and sacrifice a revenue building activity.